# jqueryUI resizable resize event not working

Tags: jquery-ui, resizable

I have a right resizable div:

```
<div id="resizable"></div>
```

but the resize event of the resizable api is not firing:

```
$( "#resizable" ).resizable({handles: 'e'}).on( "resize", function(event, ui) {console.log('resized!');} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following syntax works:

```
$( "#resizable" ).resizable(
              {handles: 'e',
                resize: function(e, ui) {
                      console.log('resized!');
                    }
              }
            );
```